# mysql: duplicate entry for primary key

Tags: mysql, ruby

I was running my ruby scripts to load in to mysql. It has an error:

> Mysql::Error: Duplicate entry '4444281482' for key 'PRIMARY'

Where my primary key is Auto-increment ID (Big-INT). I was running the script in multiple terminals with different data using screen, to load into the same table. This problem never happened before, but when it happens, all the scripts in different terminals are likely to suffer from that problem. The dataset is different. It seems to happen randomly.
What is likely to be the cause?
Why there would be duplicate in an auto-increment field?

Comment: You may be reaching the upper limit of your data type. Additionally, your table may be corrupted and you can attempt to run a repair on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mention that you are running the script from different terminals using different data. According to the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html), and assuming your engine is InnoDB, since each transaction is inserting a different amount of rows against an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column, the engine may not know how many rows will be retrieved in advance. This could possibly explain why you are receiving a duplicate key error. With the use of a table-level lock held to the end of the statement, only one `INSERT` statement can execute at a time and the generation of auto-increment numbers won't interleave.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure I had this problem - it has nothing to do with client (I mean its reproducible in both my app, query browser, cli client etc.).

If you don't bother with gaps in your id numeration you can try

```
ALTER TABLE `tableName` AUTO_INCREMENT = 4444281492;
```

(of course you can try to add more than 10 indexes, like 100000 to be sure ;) you can always revert counter to old value with same query)

This will change your auto increment counter to greater number and potentially skip invalid indexes - although I have no idea what is the cause of this issue (in my case it persisted durign mysqld restart or entire machine reboot)

oh and I should add - I did it on dev server, if this is production I would advice further investigation.